# Spotify iOS SDK and App Transport Security ios9

Tags: spotify, ios9, info.plist, app-transport-security

I'm using spotify sdk in my app. In ios 8 all was ok, but now when I'm trying to connect I got error

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
```

I added this lines in .plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>api.spotify.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>1.0</string>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>accounts.spotify.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>1.0</string>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

But it doesn't help. So, can anybody please help me to configure .plist in right way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>cloudfront.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```